# WPF XAML Change Style color based on SystemColor.HighlightBrushKey 's opacity?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors

I have XamDataGrids that i want to set colors for their "Active" and "Selected" rows app-wide.  I created a ResourceDictionary and got that done no problem.  But, how can i base one of the colors off of the other, which is a system color, by changing its opacity in pure XAML (or with a converter maybe)?  I thought about making a color and changing its opacity in code, but i want it to by dynamic, so if the user changed the System's highlight color, my custom color doesn't just stay the same.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundActive" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSelected" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
    <!--Want to set opacity of the BackgroundSelected color to 0.7 or so-->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work this way:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightSelectedColor" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" Opacity="0.7"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundActive" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundSelected" Value="{StaticResource HighlightSelectedColor}" />
    </Style>
```